# React user.name Undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using Auth0 username to determine some conditional rendering.  In one place, it works perfectly as expected.  In another, which appears to me to be setup the exact same way, it does not.  Can anyone tell me why it works in one and not the other?

This one works perfectly, to show some analytics based on users:

```
import React from 'react';
import StatsFull from './StatsFull';
import StatsSummary from './StatsSummary';
import StatsSummaryCurrentYear from './StatsSummaryCurrentYear';
import StatsSummaryLastYear from './StatsSummaryLastYear';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const ClientSurveyStats = () => {

    const { user } = useAuth0();
    

    if (user.name === "email1@email.com" || user.name === "email2@email.com" || user.name === "email3@email.com") {
        return <StatsFull />
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <StatsSummaryCurrentYear />
                <StatsSummaryLastYear />
            </div>
            
        )
    }

}

export default ClientSurveyStats;
```

However, THIS file gives me the error of: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` I cannot see the difference.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const MenuBar = () => {

  const { user } = useAuth0();

if (user.name === "email1@email.com" || user.name === "email2@email.com" || user.name === "email3@email.com") {
        return (
            <div>
                <button href="/billingcalculator">
                  <i className="fa-duotone fa-face-tongue-money fa-2x"></i>
                  <div>Billing<br/>Calculator</div>
                </button>
            </div>
       )
    }
       
}

export default MenuBar;
```

Comment: `user` is undefined - so maybe the user is not logged in or something?

Comment: Hhhmmm... that's a good thing to point to.  I'll look there, although the app won't even compile because of this error.

Comment: you could either return early from this by doing: `if(user === undefined) return null` or use modern syntax to make sure this error does not exists `if(user?.name === "email1@email.com" ...etc)`